# HyperV Failover

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I am looking to setup a 2 server HyperV environment with a Dell SAN in the back. I am setting them in cluster format and have 2008 r2 Enterprise servers for the hosts. Is there any other software that I need to get the failover configured. Dell is saying yes and MS site is saying no.

Comment: What are dell saying you need?

Comment: I'm guessing it might be the MPIO software?

Comment: A real backup solution does not come out of the box!

Comment: in other words whats your hardware vss provider

Comment: also the backup software has to be aware of the csv, if you have DPM then your covered if not then you'll need to find a solution

Comment: Symantec Backup Exec 2010 R2 with Hyper-V agent is CSV aware, however it may not be suitable for very large infrastructure, as it redirects all IO through a master node for the duration of the backup.

Comment: basically my point is that oob there is no viable backup solution. So if this is a production enviro then dell is correct in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need any additional software. As others have mentioned you can use System Center Virtual Machine Manager, but it is not required. The two tools you will need are:

- Hyper-V Manager
- Failover Cluster Manager

What you're trying to do is detailed in these two video; I highly recommend watching them.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/6-hyper-v-r2-failover--live-migration.aspx?query=1

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/hyper-v-server-2008-r2-bare-metal-to-live-migration-in-about-an-hour.aspx

We're doing an almost identical implementation, with two R410 servers and an MD3220i back end. My R410's arrived this morning, so I'm excited to get it set up.

Answer (score 0):

There's other software that you 'can' use, but with R2 you can use CSV (clustered shared volumes) which is included with the Windows OS.  You'll need to setup a cluster and CSV volumes.  It's all possible with the 'out of the box' software.

Answer (score 0):

Other software such as Virtual Machine Manager and Systems Operations Manager should be used to manage production environments, however they are not required.